# How to write user defined exceptions in Visual C++ unmanaged code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, unmanaged

I would like to know how to write unmanaged exceptions in Visual C++?

```
#include <string>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;

class GraphException : public Exception
{
public:
    GraphException() { }
//  GraphException(string message) : Exception (message)
//  { }
//  GraphException(string message, Exception inner) : Exception (message, inner)
//  { }
};
```

this does not work i get the following error,

> Error 1   error C3625: 'GraphException': an unmanaged type cannot derive
>   from a managed type
>   'System::Exception'   c:\breadthfirst\graph\graphexception.h  10  1   breadthFirst

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Derive from `std::exception` instead of `Exception`.

Better yet derive from one of the more specialized exceptions in [`stdexcept`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/t65b74ad).

Comment: Just as an aside you can `throw` anything you like. It can be any class/struct you like... or even a primitive type.

Comment: Also, be sure to `throw MyException(foo);`, not `throw new MyException(foo);`

Comment: @Kathy Also, be aware that `std::exception` in VC++ has several non-standard constructors defined. The only standard constructors are `exception() noexcept` and the copy constructor. VC++ defines a `const char *` member variable to point to the reason for the exception, this is also not part of the C++ standard.